# Сохранение состояния приложения при сворачивании

Tags: android

Разметка MainActivity следующая:

```
LinearLayout
-AppBarLayout
-DrawerLayout
   -FrameLayoutContent
   -FrameLayoutNavigation
```

Допустим мой `FrameLayoutNavigation` содержит две категории (`Категория1` и `Категория2`). `FrameLayoutContent` отображает содержимое каждой категории, это хорошо. Но если в процессе работы я перейду в `Категория2` и сверну приложение, то при развороте на экране отображается содержимое `Категория1`.
Как сохранить состояние приложения при сворачивании, чтобы при развороте отображалось содержимое `Категория2`?

Пытаюсь сделать следующим образом, но это не работает (код из `MainActivity`):

```
 @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            toolbarname = getSupportActionBar().getTitle().toString();
           outState.putString("toolbarname", toolbarname);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            toolbarname = savedInstanceState.getString("toolbarname");
            if (toolbarname.equals("Категория1")){
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment1().commit();  
            } else if (toolbarname.equals("Категория2")){
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new Fragment2().commit(); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Самое тривиальное решение -- сохранять номер текущей позиции.

Comment: @post_zeew это понятно. Какие методы использовать и где?
Прочитал про методы onSaveInstanceState и onRestoreInstanceState, попробовал сделать - не выходит.

Comment: Да, методы эти. Покажите, как используете их.

Comment: @post_zeew добавил к вопросу эти куски кода. Спасибо за ваше внимание по моему вопросу :)

Comment: В методе `onRestoreInstanceState(...)` после строки `toolbarname = savedInstanceState.getString("toolbarname");` выведите в лог `toolbarname`. Какое значение в нем будет?

Comment: @post_zeew забыл добавить самое главное! при повороте экрана `toolbarname` выводится в лог в двух методах. А при сворачивании/разворачивании приложения - нет.

Comment: При сворачивании приложения, в большинстве случаев, ничего изменятся и не должно. При сворачивании/разворачивании категории неверно отображаются?

Comment: @post_zeew допустим toolbarname "Категория2", во фрагменте отображается содержимое "Категория2". При сворачивании/разворачивании приложения тулбар и фрагмент меняет свои значения на "категория1".

Comment: Выложите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Возможно, кто-нибудь поможет.

Comment: Ах да, перед этим выложите полностью код активити, может и так понятно будет.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то методы `onSaveInstanceState` и `onRestoreInstanceState` срабатывают только при повороте экрана.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то методы `onSaveInstanceState` и `onRestoreInstanceState` срабатывают только при повороте экрана.

Comment: Именно так. При сворачивании разворачивании вызываются `onPause` / `onResume`

Comment: Минутку, а что автор понимает под сворачиванием/разворачиванием? Случайно не закрытие/открытие?

Comment: @Flippy при нажатии на физическую кнопку "back" приложение закрывается, но как бы все равно в трее еще висит. И при открытии приложение запускается заново с входной точки так скажем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте какую-нибудь **переменную** для обозначения типа/номера категории и `SharedPreferences` для ее сохранения. При изменении категории, меняйте значение в переменной.

В методе `onPause`, сохраняйте эту переменную.

```
mSharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.number), mNumber);
editor.apply();
```

В методе `onCreate` или где нужно, восстанавливайте ее значение.

```
mSharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
mNumber = mSharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.number), 1);
```

Перед тем как загружать/отображать категорию, проверяйте значение переменной.

Comment: Отличная идея! Попробую воспользоваться ей!